# Module never used warning while building Angular 9 library

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-library, ng-packagr

Recently I updated one of my projects from Angular 8 to Angular 9.
 When I try to build the library I am getting this warning

```
__read' is imported from external module 'tslib' but never used
```

[image]

This warning was not there previously with version 8. I tried to find the root cause of it but I couldn't.
There is one github [issue](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1543) related to this but there was no fix or workaround.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using spread operator (...) in your project somewhere.

And maybe the webpack build config which angular cli is using in angular 9 is importing this from tslib, but didn't use it. Maybe in upcoming releases they remove this unnecessary import

Comment: Thanks for the response. So are you suggesting me to remove spread operator??

Comment: No, this warning will not impact your code. This is only an import in angular internal build config. so ignore for now.

Comment: Yes it's not a blocking issue. But I was wondering, are there any fix/workaround rahter waiting to fix this by ng-packagr or Angular